# How do I pass a $row(["datefieldname"] as a variable to a MySQL DATE_FORMAT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Been looking at this and trying everything for a few hours now. Trying to build a website page that takes a MySQL database of deceased classmates and displays a picture of them and their obituary.  "BirthDate" and "DeathDate" are defined in my classmateinfo database "rip" table as "date", so they are in YYYY-MM-DD format.  I'm trying to convert them into %M %d, %Y format (January 1, 1957) to display on the website page as a part of the obituary.

Here is the pertinent part of my code:

```
  <?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "classmateinfo");
  if ($conn-> connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM rip ORDER BY DeathDate";
  $result = $conn-> query($sql);
  if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
      $i = 0;
      while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        // there much code before and after this to display everything in the obit           
        echo "<div class=\"birthdeathdatesection\">";
        $birthdate = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT($row["BirthDate"], "%M %d, %Y")";
        $deathdate = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT($row["DeathDate"], "%M %d, %Y")";
        echo $birthdate . " - " . $deathdate . "</div>";
      }
    }
```

The exception thrown when running it is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\testsite\wp-content\themes\altertest\ripslidertest.php on line 178

I've tried every form of the DATE_FORMAT statement I could think of.  I'd appreciate anyone out there's help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$birthdate = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT($row["BirthDate"], "%M %d, %Y")";
```

The quote for the `$row` index breaks the string construction. Fixing that though will lead to additional issues (e.g. it is a SQL string, not a value), just construct the date in PHP.

```
$birthdate = date('F d, Y', strtotime($row["BirthDate"]));
```

rough demo without DB interaction: https://3v4l.org/6AkKI. Do the same for `$deathdate`.

Alternatively you could use `date_format` in original query, just need to change up the quotes:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BirthDate, "%M %d, %Y") as birthdate_formatted, DATE_FORMAT(DeathDate, "%M %d, %Y") as deathdate_formatted FROM rip ORDER BY DeathDate';
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
      $i = 0;
      while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['birthdate_formatted'] . '-' . $row['deathdate_formatted'];
      }
}
```

Add other columns into the `SELECT` list as needed.

Comment: Thank you!!!  That worked, where my attempt echo date_format($row["BirthDate"],"F j, Y"); did not.  I'll look up the strtotime function ... guess I need to understand that.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Alan-Seattle That converts a plain text data set to an epoch timestamp, `date` takes epoch as second parameter and displays it in format based on first parameter. Can read about formats here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php